# Cordova media plugin and local files in Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, audio, windows-phone-8, media

I want to port cordova app to Windows Phone 8 platform. But there's come troubles with sound.

There was string new Media('/android_asset/sounds/bell.wav').

When I changing param to 'sounds/bell.wav', error code is 1.
If I put 'x-wmapp0:www/sounds/bell.wav' or 'file:///www/sounds/bell.wav' there's no errors but sounds is not playing.

URLs from Internet (files and streams) playing well.

Please help me to find a way to play local files from app on wp8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mypath = location.pathname;

var idx = mypath.lastIndexOf('/');

var backgroundMusicFilePath = mypath.substring(0, idx + 1) + "audio/BackgroundMusic.mp3";

app.backgroundMusic = new Media(backgroundMusicFilePath);
```

The local mp3 for my project is stored under the www\audio folder. Getting the local file is tricky because it differs for iOS, Android and WP8.

Comment: Right param is 'www/sounds/bell.wav'. Thanks!

Comment: In windows 10 apps I had to use location.href instead of location.pathname. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the below on windows 10/windows phone universal

```js
//index.js
var url = document.getElementById("idAHidden").href
console.log(url)
```

```html
<!--index.html -->
<a href="" style="visibility:hidden" id="idAHidden"></a>
```